# Add text and change style to post programmatically depending on category

Tags: posts, content

Can someone please let me know how to add text to posts depending on category and how to change the styling of a post depending on category ?

I tried to add the function below to `functions.php`, but it wipes all content of a post:

```php
function josh_content_link ($content) {
    return 'Welcome';
}

add_filter ('the_content', 'josh_content_link',10,2);
```

Comment: You really need to first **understand** about WordPress hooks, e.g. where and when does a filter run, what parameters available to the callback function and what should it return, so I hope you've checked the links I shared via your other question. You also need to have a solid foundation on general PHP things like user-defined functions and working with strings, variables, etc. And as for this question, your function was simply returning `Welcome`, so of course the post content got "wiped", and you should instead do something like `return "Welcome $content";` or `return "$content Welcome";`.

Comment: You'll also want to read up on [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) regarding the "depending on category" part of your question.

Comment: Can you help with the interpretation, not only the sources  ? In other words, the sources you mentioned are written in highly technical and tedious jargon. I am economist by profession and I have heard time reading such texts. Therefore, would you mind interpreting where and when does a filter run ? What role does a function play in filter ? Why is the function called "callback" and is there another name which can be used instead of the confusing term "callback" ?

Comment: What is the interpretation of "registering sidebar" ? What is the example and the meaning.

Comment: @TBVTranslation please tag the users you're replying to, otherwise they'd never know you've posted a reply. And as for "registering sidebar", it essentially means adding a [widget area](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/), an area where you can add [widgets](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/) to. But looking at your [recent question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/408377/137402), I believe you already know what registering a sidebar means. ✌

Comment: And yes of course, we'd be happy to help you with the interpretation, if you had explicitly asked it in your post (i.e. this question). As for callback or [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), it's just a PHP function which does (and then might return) something, and that *can* be called from within another function. And actually, your `josh_content_link()` function is an example of a callback which must return something since it's hooked onto a *filter* hook.