# Interpretation and explanation of register sidebar

Tags: themes, user-registration, sidebar

can someone please explain the following:

1. esc_html
2. `'<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">'`

From the following block of code:

```
function daniels_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Footer 1', 'theme_name' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'theme_name' ),
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'daniels_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: `esc_html__()` retrieves and escapes the translation of a text, whereas those `%1$s` and `%2$s` are placeholders which will be replaced with the widget ID and class name, respectively. See the documentation for more details: [`esc_html__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/) and [`register_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/).

Comment: @SallyCJ you should post that as an answer, I'd also note that `esc_html__(` is shorthand for `esc_html( __(` and does 2 things

Answer (score 1):

First off, [`register_sidebar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/) is used to add a [widget area](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/), an area where you can add [widgets](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/) to.

*And in short, `esc_html__()` retrieves and escapes the translation of a text, whereas those `%1$s` and `%2$s` are placeholders which will be replaced with the widget ID and class name, respectively.*

**More details on `esc_html__()`**

[`esc_html__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/) does two things:

- First, it calls [`translate()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/translate/) which retrieves the translation of a text.
- Secondly, it calls [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) which escapes HTML tags in a text.

So `esc_html__()` is *equivalent to `esc_html( translate( 'text', 'text-domain' ) )`* and is a *shorthand for `esc_html( __( 'text', 'text-domain' ) )`* (that uses [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) which calls `translate()`).

And if there is no translation, or the text domain isn’t loaded, then the original text is simply escaped and returned.

So for example, `esc_html__( 'Hello <b>World</b>!', 'text-domain' )` might return:

- `Hello &lt;b&gt;World&lt;/b&gt;!` — not translated, but escaped
- `Ciao &lt;b&gt;mondo&lt;/b&gt;!` — translated (to Italiano), and then escaped

**More details on the `%1$s` and `%2$s` (placeholders)**

Excerpt from the `register_sidebar()` documentation:

> **'before_widget'**
> *(string)* HTML content to prepend to each widget's HTML output when assigned to this sidebar. Receives the widget's ID attribute as `%1$s`
> and class name as `%2$s`. Default is an opening list item element.

So for example, if you added a Paragraph *block* widget to the `Footer 1` sidebar, then on the front-end (where you called `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )`) you would see the `<section>` tag like so:

```html
<section id="block-8" class="widget widget_block widget_text">
```

Which means `%1$s` was replaced with `block-8`, whereas `%2$s` was replaced with `widget_block widget_text`.

- **Note:** The class name for a [*block widget*](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/block-based-widgets-editor-in-wordpress-5-8/) defaults to  `widget_block`, but for backwards compatibility, if a block widget contains a block that has an equivalent legacy widget, the legacy widget’s class name is added to the list just like the `widget_text` above.

  So for example if I had used [the Classic Widgets plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-widgets/) and added a Text widget to the above sidebar, the `<section>` would instead look like this where the `%1$s` was replaced with `text-2`, whereas `%2$s` was replaced with **just** `widget_text`:

  ```html
  <section id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
  ```